# Is there a way to auto shrink the log file in IIS?

Tags: iis, logging

Is is possible to auto shrink the log file in IIS or is there an option provide in IIS. The only way I know is to compress the log file directory. If there is any way to auto shrink function that will shrink the file for a particular period.

Answer (score 3):

In IIS the log files can be set up to start a new log file each day.  There is no compression capability in IIS for the logs.  Best bet is to setup a job that will archive the log files somewhere else to prevent running out of disk space.

Answer (score 2):

Why not roll the logs daily, and remove files older than 'n' days?